# Fibonacci Memoization : Cannot understand the reason for TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

Just started learning about Dynamic Programming and memoization using generation of the *nth* Fibonacci number as an example. I wrote the following code (actually took help from a website), erased it and tried to write it once myself. There is a problem with the return call (TypeError) that I can't understand.

I fixed it by indenting the **return memo[x]** call below the **if** statement and the program worked.

I just want to know the reason for the error in the following code:

What does the code do?

1) Creates a function to memoize an input function

2) Sub function 'helper', which checks if the output of the entered function is in the dictionary called 'memo'. If not, then it updates the dictionary as required

The entire function returns a number from memo (if it's already in memo) to avoid unnecessary branching.

3) Creates a function to generate Fibonacci numbers by using the recursion algorithm.

4) Memoizes the Fib No. generator and print the *nth* Fib No.

```py
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
            return memo[x]
    return helper
def fib(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

fib = memoize(fib)

print(fib(10))
```

I expect it to return the *nth* Fib. No. but instead it returns an error in the **return memo[x]** call.

Error Message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(fib(10))
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 5, in helper
    memo[x] = f(x)
  File "E:\euler25.py", line 14, in fib
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

What does this error message mean?

Comment: You don't return anything when you already have that in `memo`, so it implicitly returns None. Un-indent (shift+tab) your `return` line. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with the `return` statement scope of the memoization function:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(x):
        if x not in memo:
            memo[x] = f(x)
        # function should return always the memoized value
        return memo[x]
    return helper
```

The problem is that at some point your `helper` function returns a `None` which makes the fib funciton try to `+` between an `int` and a `None`, which triggers the `TypeError`

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/LavenderIntentPiracy)

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious to know what was it trying to return in the my wrong code.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler If a function ends without reaching a return statement, it returns `None`.

Comment: @YourAverageEuler check the brief explanation